# Do certain usb ports work better on my IBM T60?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, wireless-networking, sp3, headset

I am using a Microsoft wireless phone ear piece and I have had the receiver plugged into the USB port on the Left Hand side. I have been getting intermittent success with the signal.

I have recently tried plugging it in to one of the ports on the top Right Hand side, and it seems that I am getting a better signal.

Is there a difference between the ports?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there's any intentional difference between the ports, but there could be a difference in radio frequency interference from nearby components in the laptop, or whether there were obstructions between you and the receiver when you were testing it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that one of the ports is USB 2.0 and the other is USB 1.0 or 1.1

USB 2.0 is the newer technology and it supports faster rates of transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems improbable, but the possible solution might be cable length, the shorter the cable the better the signal and lesser the attenuation and thus better the transmission rate.

Oh and maybe the faster 1 might be USB 2.0, if you get almost double or thrice the speed, then it definitely is a USB 2.0 port.

Comment: Thanks coneslayer, dexter and adeel.
They are all 2.0 ports.
There is nothing between the device and the computer or the headset. The cable length is all wrapped up as it was when I received the device and it is sitting about 8 inchs from the computer, about 2 feet from my head.

Comment: Generally the cable length problem only comes into play when your talking in terms of feet (meters). A few inches here and there though doesn't *usually* matter.